# Multiple text items in List view item

Tags: c#, listview, windows-10, win-universal-app, subitem

Does anyone know of the correct way to add multiple sections of text to one listview item when using Windows 10 universal apps in C#? Items.subitems doesn't seem to work. Say my two string I want to display in a single list item are stored in...

```
    public class listContent
    {
        public string heading { get; set; }
        public string subHeading { get; set; }
    }
```

Would doing something similar to this work?

```
listContent listItem = new listContent();
listItem.heading = "HEADING";
listItem.subHeading = "subheading";
lsvTransactions.Items.Add(listItem);
```

Regards
Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to DataBind to a custom DataTemplate. Considering you already have `lsvTransactions` name ListView. Here is what you should do.

1. Create a List of `listContent` in your .cs file showed below

   ```
   public class MainPage : Page
   {
       public List<listContent> ContentList {get; set;}
       .....
   ```
2. Add Items to this `ContentList` in your code like you did above.
3. After adding items add the following line to point to data source.

   ```
   lsvTransactions.DataContext = ContentList;
   ```
4. Create a ListView like shown below with DataTemplate

   ```
   <ListView x:Name="lsvTransactions" ItemsSource={Binding}>
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                           <StackPanel>
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding heading}"/>
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding subheading}"/>
                           </StackPanel>
                   </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
   ```

Comment: `<ListView x:Name="lsvTransactions" ItemsSource={Binding}>` this line returns an error on "ItemsSource={Binding}. When I change it to "ItemsSource="{Binding}" the error goes but nothing appears in the list box

Answer (score 2):

As it was said maybe if you give us more info on your code, we can help better. I post you here a sample of a Listbox (which is similar to the listview) with the definition of the ItemTemplate for the elements I use and how to bind the items to the listbox and the fields in the items to the elements put in the Listbox.

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MeasureUnits, Mode=OneWay}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMeasureUnit, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0" 
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}" Style="{StaticResource idStyle}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" Style="{StaticResource desStyle}"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DestinationUnitsInSource}" Style="{StaticResource numStyle}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SourceUnitsInDestination}" Style="{StaticResource numStyle}" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Wrap Panel is not supported in Universal and IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem is not supported, but I upvote this :)

Comment: You can simply remove all the unsupported code here. I don't think he wants a `WrapPanel` in his case, a `StackPanel` would do.

Answer (score 0):

In my XAML:

```
 <ListView x:Name="listView">
```

In my C#:

```
listView.Items.Add(item);
```

Where Item is an object with multiple text elements.

If you post code I can be more specific.

Comment: Even though if you add it to listView like this, your `ListView` will have no idea how to show these these two elements :) You will need to define a DataTemplate to make it possible.